# Setting {pagination_url}

Tags: pagination

I am having a weird issue where my {pagination_url} is defaulting to an old server path. Where can I go to make sure that this path is properly set.

I have no experience searching the database to be honest with you so guidance will be needed.

I did use Deploy Helper each time when moving the site from server to server if that helps at all.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Fixed issue by adding in paginate_base="news/index" but would like a fix so that pagination_url is properly set.

Comment: Check your Site URL setting (Admin --> General).

Comment: Already did and it is correct. {site_url} works great! even did a database search for the old URL and it was not found which is crazy. paginate_base setting seemed to work just fine. Appreciate the help!!!!